# How to Left-Align HTML Table, created from an Excel Range, in an Outlook Body?

Tags: html, css, excel, vba, outlook

I want to copy a selected range from Excel to the body of an Outlook mail (Office 2013).

The table is pasting with Center Align.

I want to paste with left-align or modify the HTML table object to change its properties (e.g. alignment, word wrapping as is done with WordEditor Inspector).

I tried `objNewEmail.HTMLBody = "<table align = ""left"">" & objTextStream.ReadAll & "</table>"`.
This embeds my table within another table and inexplicably, the new table is generated with Text-Wrapping on.

I tried `<p align>` and a couple CSS styling options none of which gave any errors but they didn't change anything on the email.

```vb
Sub Macro1()

Selection.CurrentRegion.Select

Dim objSelection As Excel.Range
Dim objTempWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objTempWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strTempHTMLFile As String
Dim objTempHTMLFile As Object
Dim objFileSystem As Object
Dim objTextStream As Object
Dim objOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNewEmail As Outlook.MailItem

'Copy the selection
Set objSelection = Selection
Selection.Copy

'Paste the copied selected ranges into a temp worksheet
Set objTempWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
Set objTempWorksheet = objTempWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'Keep the values, column widths and formats in pasting
With objTempWorksheet.Cells(1)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With

'Save the temp worksheet as a HTML file
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strTempHTMLFile = objFileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2).Path & "\Temp for Excel" & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss") & ".htm"
Set objTempHTMLFile = objTempWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, strTempHTMLFile, objTempWorksheet.Name, objTempWorksheet.UsedRange.Address)
objTempHTMLFile.Publish (True)

'Create a new email
Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNewEmail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Read the HTML file data and insert into the email body
Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strTempHTMLFile)
objNewEmail.HTMLBody = "<p> See below table. </p>" & objTextStream.ReadAll
objNewEmail.HTMLBody = "<table align=""left"">" & objTextStream.ReadAll & "</table>" & "<p align=""left"">" & objNewEmail.HTMLBody & "</p>"

objNewEmail.HTMLBody = objNewEmail.HTMLBody & "<p> Thank you </p>"

objNewEmail.Display

objTextStream.Close
objTempWorkbook.Close (False)
objFileSystem.DeleteFile (strTempHTMLFile)
End Sub
```

The table is Centered but I want it Aligned Left.
[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Hard to really know what will work without also knowing what `objTextStream.ReadAll` returns. I just tested this: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm and it left aligned like you want, because of this code: `RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")` - but again, it's not going to work if your HTML is different than what it returned from that tutorial, and you did not include that in your question.

Comment: In other words, if `objTextStream.ReadAll` already includes a table element, you cant just put another table element around it like you are doing and expect it to work. You need to modify the existing table element instead.

Comment: Post the HTML for the email screenshot so we can read what it's doing. Send the email to yourself and then open it and View Source

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but maybe the solution I found could help. By reading `RangetoHTML` value, I noticed that the replacement of `align=center x:publishsource=` with `align=left x:publishsource=` is not occurring because there is a line break after `align=center`.

To fix the problem, just use

`RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center", "align=left")`

instead of

`RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")`